# Layering elements on top of each other with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been playing around with this sliding drop-down jquery menu. I moved the drop-down area up a little bit with a negative margin. I was hoping there would be a way to layer the drop down on top of the parent element that is the trigger for the action. I tried z-index but no luck. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here it is live: http://daveywhitney.com/overlay/sliding_menu.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sliding Menu Tutorial | HV-DESIGNS.CO.UK</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
</div>

<div id="button">
<div id="trigger">
<img src="images/button.png" width="184" height="32" class="menu_class" />
</div>
<ul class="the_menu">
<li><a href="#">A Website #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Website #2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Link #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Link #2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Website #3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Website #4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Link #3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">A Link #4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    background-color: #333333;
}

#container {
    margin: auto;
    width: 490px;
}

#header {
    background-image: url(images/header.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 42px;
    width: 490px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#button {
    height: 32px;
    width: 184px;
    margin: auto;
}

ul, li {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
}

.menu_class {
    border:1px solid #1c1c1c;

}
#trigger {
    z-index:-1;
}
.the_menu {
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    margin:-50px 0 0 50px;
    z-index:100;
}

.the_menu li {
    background-color: #302f2f;
}

.the_menu li a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:10px; 
    display:block;
}

.the_menu li a:hover {
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #F00880;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

you need to set the CSS property for the elements in question. Set `position: relative` for the "parent" element. Then apply a `position: absolute` to the "child" element.

This makes the child element "absolute" positioned "relative" to the parent. Then use CSS to position the child. eg.

```
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

which will match the top-left corners of the parent and child elements

Answer (score 6):

In order for `z-index` to work on an element you have to be using [`the CSS property "position"`](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the menu's `position` to `relative`, z-index won't work on elements positioned as `static`, which they all are by default.